# Check if HTML has attribute and after that remove style from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-dyslexic-applied="true">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="material-icons pr-1" style="font-family: Material Icons">open_in_new</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am trying to do is to remove this `style` from the `<span class="material-icons"></span>` if HTML has this atribute `data-dyslexic-applied="true"`

This is my JS code:

```
 if (!$('html').attr('data-dyslexic-applied')) {
      $(' span.material-icons ').removeAttr("style");
     }
```

My code doesn't work, can anybody try to help me with this? What is the best approach for checking if a certain element has an attribute?

Comment: @connexo it would be better to link to a relevant explanation of [how to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than saying they are "required" to manage their question and including bold text, which comes across a bit heavy-handed. Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for reference.

Comment: I didn't realize this was asked/answered more than 2 weeks ago. That changes things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: `document.documentElement` is the shortcut to access the `html` element in any HTML `document`.

Use `hasAttribute` if all you care about is the mere presence of that attribute (and you don't care about its value):

```js
if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute('data-dyslexic-applied')) {
  document.querySelector('span.material-icons.pr-1').removeAttribute('style');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-dyslexic-applied="true">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="material-icons pr-1" style="font-family: Material Icons; color: red;">open_in_new</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you also need to check the value, use the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
if (document.documentElement.dataset.dyslexicApplied === 'true') {
  document.querySelector('span.material-icons.pr-1').removeAttribute('style');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-dyslexic-applied="true">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="material-icons pr-1" style="font-family: Material Icons; color: red;">open_in_new</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

If it's not a `data-`attribute, use `getAttribute`:

```js
if (document.documentElement.getAttribute('title') === 'foo') {
  document.querySelector('span.material-icons.pr-1').removeAttribute('style');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html title="foo">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="material-icons pr-1" style="font-family: Material Icons; color: red;">open_in_new</span>
    </body>
</html>
```